# Создание галереи пользователя

Tags: php, база-данных, структуры-данных, файловая-система

Созрел интересный вопрос, у нас есть **база пользователей**, у каждого из них есть возможность создавать **свою галерею**, или даже несколько.

Как наиболее **оптимально**, со стороны **скорости и надежности**, создать структуру хранения данных. Думаю между двумя вариантами - полностью всю нагрузку дать на **БД**, или больше на **файловую систему**.

*В первом случае:* Все фото хранятся в **общей директории**, ссылки на картинки помещаем в *БД*.

*Во втором:* каждому пользователю создаем **свою директорию** в которую загружаются картинки и при извлечении фото просто **сканируем ее** и выводим все у чего есть подходящее разрешение. Параллельно есть *БД* с названием файлов - для удаления.

Comment: Обычно используют второй вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того что вам сейчас необходимо и какие перспективы на будущее возможны. Организация директорий в виде `пользователь/ID_альбома/файлы` привязывает галерею к пользователю. В таком случае необходимо понять есть ли необходимость привязывать галерею к пользователю.

Например галереи могут опубликовывать как публичные. Кроме того что произойдет когда пользователя удалят? Должна ли сохраняться галерея?

Например возможно такая ситуация. 
Какой нибудь пользователь может сохранить публичную галерею у себя в избранном. Что должно произойти если автор галереи удалит свой аккаунт? Должна ли галерея удаляться из избранной подписчика? Если нет то привязка аккаунт - галерея не верная.

Для большой гибкости можно применить такое решение.
В файловой системе галерея будет выглядеть так `albums/ album_ID/images`.

База данных может быть организованна вот так

- отдельная таблица albums в которой будет весь список альбомов.
- И еще одна таблица `user_albums` в которой будет пара ключей
  `user_ID,album_ID`.

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно универсальный ответ - интересовался не для конкретной задачи, а для общего развития, и понимания каким образом лучше обходить такое слабое место как БД